# C/C++/C# Force window to be on top

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, always-on-top

Is the there a way to force ***another*** window to be on top? *Not* the application's window, but *another* one, already running on the system. (Windows, C/C++/C#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Win32 API [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(VS.85).aspx).   It takes an HWND.

You could also use the Win32 API [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) which also allows you to do things like make the window a top-level window.

Comment: The seccond link is incorrect, you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx

Could you also suggest an example on this function?

Comment: @Levo: Thanks I mustn't have copied it to the clipboard correctly before I pasted.

Answer (score 10):

```
SetWindowPos(that_window_handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

`BringWindowToTop` moves the window to the top of the Z-order (for now) but does *not* make it a topmost window.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: @Levo:just substitute the handle of the window you want on top in place of `that_window_handle` in the snippet above.

Answer (score 3):

BringWindowToTop() has no effect if you want to bring a applications window from behind (or minimized) to front. The following code does this trick reliable:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
```

Comment: It is slow in win XP.

Comment: Working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) {
     wchar_t buff[255];

    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
        GetWindowText(hWnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
        //wprintf(L"%s\n", buff);
        wstring ws = buff;
        if (ws.find(L"Firefox") != ws.npos)
        {
            ::SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(){
    BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows( EnumWindowsProc, NULL );
}
```