# How to focus opencv window after opening it?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am displaying some images with imshow and waitKey() only works when I click the window after it has opened. Is there any way to do this automatically so I do not have to click it everytime?

Comment: This is more related to how your platform handles new windows. This question might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417531/opencv-how-to-force-the-image-window-to-appear-on-top-of-other-windows .

Comment: On Linux (and other Unix operating systems) there's usually a way to request the window manager to bring a window to the front. On (modern) Windows OSs you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Do this before using waitKey() to create a window "My Image" and focus it"

```
namedWindow("My Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);

HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL,_T("My Image"));
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
```

(`#include<tchar.h>` for `_T`)